# azure subscription coadmin cannot create resources in subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We (all the co-admins) have been having a problem with not being able to create resources on our azure subscriptions unless we sign in as the account administrator, even though we've been assigned co-administrator rights to those subscriptions. We're also part of the active directory that such subscriptions trust as we were assigned global admin credentials there also.

When we, the co-admins, sign into any of the subscriptions in question and check the properties of them, we can see that we have administrator's rights there.

Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Jesant